# Comparing timedelta fields

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I am looking at file delivery times and can't work out how to compare two timedelta fields using a for loop if statement.

`time_diff` is the difference between `cob_date` and `last_update_time`

`average_diff` is based on the average for a particular file

I want to find the delay for each row.

I have been able to produce a column `delay` using `average_diff - time_diff`

However, when the `average_diff - time_diff < 0` I just want to return `delay = 0` as this is not a delay.

I have made a for loop but this isn't working and I don't know why. I'm sure the answer is very simple but I can't get there.

```
test_pv_import_v2['delay2'] = pd.to_timedelta('0')

for index, row in test_pv_import_v2.iterrows():
    if test_pv_import_v2['time_diff'] > test_pv_import_v2['average_diff'] :
        test_pv_import_v2['delay2'] = test_pv_import_v2['time_diff'] - test_pv_import_v2['average_diff']
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set `0 Timedelta` by condition:

```
mask = test_pv_import_v2['time_diff'] > test_pv_import_v2['average_diff']
s = (test_pv_import_v2['time_diff'] - test_pv_import_v2['average_diff'])

test_pv_import_v2['delay2'] = s.where(mask, pd.to_timedelta('0'))
```